# Get the number of individual substrings in a string use sql

Tags: sql

hey，all I have a table like this:

```
...    schema    ...
...    a,b,c     ...
...    b,c       ...
...    a,c       ...
```

every column schema split by ',' . then i wanna get below result:

```
label    count
a          2
b          2
c          3
```

can I do this in pure sql？

Comment: This isn't easy to handle using SQL, and you should rather fix your data model and stop storing CSV data this way.  That being said, you should also tell us what _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres).

Comment: Are you sure this is a table, it is not a CSV or some other kind of file? If it is table in that column is there any limitation like "in this column we can store only combination of `(a,b,c)`" and the maximum element number is 3?